# Where can I get the free Hebrew text of the Siddur or Benching? 

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, product-recommendation, internet, text

Where can I get the text of the siddur/*prayer book* (or at least benching/*grace*, mincha/*afternoon prayer*, and/or ma'ariv/*evening prayer*) in a free computer friendly format? I'd like to be able to make materials that include commonly needed teffilos(*prayers*) (e.g. a bencher card) on my computer.

I'd like the text to ideally be:

- In different nusachos (*versions, like Nusach Sefared or Ashkenaz*)
- Free (copyright free and free of charge)
- In a computer format that can be copied or pasted (not an image)
- In Unicode
- In Hebrew
- With Nikkudos (*Vowels*)

even if only some of the prayers are available and have only some of the features listed above, I'd be interested.

Comment: Adam, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the excellent question, which I'm sure others will find useful! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good place to start would be [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8), on Hebrew Wikisource. It looks like their texts would meet all of your criteria.

Answer (score 6):

[Online Siddur](http://www.onlinesiddur.com/)
does a pretty good job with providing the full text.
It is very nice indeed.

Comment: Meshulum, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for sharing that awesome resource! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 2):

[idaven.com](http://idaven.com) has Nusach Ari.

This might not meet all the criteria in the question, but others with the same question and fewer restrictions might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Open Siddur](http://opensiddur.org). They have directions how to create your own siddur, as well as some already created siddurim, with full attribution info (allowing one to contact the original authors).

E.g. There is a Nusach Ashkenaz siddur "Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel", dedicated to the memory of the Bad Homburg Jewish community, with the author's name and a comment thread, where he has responded to questions about it.