# Who knows of a online siddur that is not vocalized?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, prayer-book

Is there a non-vocalized siddur available online? I think being from the US I'm unaware of full text resources of Judaic text without vowels.

Comment: What for? ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6333/759

Comment: @AriA working hard to deprogram my nekkudim crutch.

Comment: Does it have to be always available online, or does it just need to be downloadable once? I found a site that will disemvowel Hebrew text. In combination with the free siddurim on the other page, you can get what you want with a little copy-pasting.

Comment: @DoubleAA That would be really helpful!

Comment: @EEE See [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16688/759) below.

Comment: To add to (or subtract from) this question, I wish there were a completely unembellished text of the _t'filos_ from start to finish - i.e. no special encoding, no formatting, no titles, no nothing, for various kinds of cutting, pasting and processing. Ideally, menu selection would allow insertion or omission of special seasonal/optional words. Anybody have one of those? Is this a separate question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use a Hebrew text [disemvowel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disemvowel)er (such as [this one](http://www.shaftek.org/downloads/blogging/attachments/2005/06/03/test.html)) and put the text from [Wikisource's Siddur](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8) in it.

Comment: disemvoweler link dead. any new ones?

Comment: https://jcuenod.github.io/hebrewTools/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded this siddur ([link](http://jewi.sh/11g32)) from the Internet, and it lacks vowels. You may or may not require an Android smartphone to access it.