# Is there an online siddur without vowels / niqqud?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book

I see that this was asked back in 2012, but perhaps the [answer has changed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16684/who-knows-of-a-online-siddur-that-is-not-vocalized) since.

Reason: as a personal project of sorts, I am attempting to produce a siddur that uses the (Paleo) Ancient Hebrew alphabet!

I can do a find and replace using unvowelized text fairly easily (I know there's probably some Perl or Bash script I could use, but running find and replace 22 times doesn't sound that bad to me).

I'm sure I've come across at least one, but that may well have been an Android app. I'm looking for the text on a website that I can C&P into Word. I've searched for תפילת שחרית , סידור etc and all I can find are vowelized texts.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. If your question is the same, then it is likely to get closed. Don't get annoyed by this, it is just how this site works. Hope that the resurfacing of the question will be enough to get you answers (although it would help if you explained why the answers of the other questions are not enough for you)

Comment: @mbloch - thanks! Link to the disemvoweler is broken, so that's not an option, as well as the link in the second response (to a siddur without niqqud).

I searched in Hebrew and have found a solution: [link](https://bit.ly/2xdWlWN)

Comment: Great. If you found a solution, you should write up as an answer on the original question and this one can be closed safely. Thanks and please keep learning with us !

Comment: Feel free to update on the progress of that siddur

Comment: I certainly will. I've always been fascinated with Ancient Israel (what they ate, how different their Hebrew is to ours). This is a very unusual project that will probably just sit on my Shabbat table, but might get some other people interested in the topic. And BTW, I'm still searching for שיר של שום and the עשר זכירות in unvowelized Hebrew.

Comment: Any updates?(?)

Answer (score 2):

[Found something suitable](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%93/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8/%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93). Only Nusach Sefard available (was hoping for Edot HaMizrah), but it will be enough to experiment with!